# SQL Server two tables with same columns but pick data with no null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below sample data, two temp tables with same structure, but I need to  get one table output, with taking best values between two tables (best values here is NO NULL's). Ignore null values between two same columns in two tables.

Table 1

```
Prog    OrderNO ORDERKey    OrigType    REBNO   REBACC
A          1    1234        FACILITY    NULL    NULL
A          2    1234        FACILITY    NULL    NULL
A          3    1234        FACILITY    NULL    NULL
```

Table 2

```
Prog    OrderNO ORDERKey    OrigType    REBNO   REBACC
A          1    NULL            NULL    1234    456
A          2    NULL            NULL    1234    456
A          3    NULL            NULL    1234    456
```

OUTPUT

```
Prog    OrderNO ORDERKey    OrigType    REBNO   REBACC
A          1    1234        FACILITY    1234    456
A          2    1234        FACILITY    1234    456
A          3    1234        FACILITY    1234    456
```

Comment: "Best values" based on the `Prog` and `OrderNo`? Is that what identifies a unique record in your data?

Answer (score 4):

Use `COALESCE()` combined with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( Table1.Prog, Table2.Prog ) AS Prog,
    COALESCE( Table1.OrderNo, Table2.OrderNo ) AS OrderNo,

    COALESCE( Table1.OrderKey, Table2.OrderKey) AS OrderKey,
    COALESCE( Table1.OrigType, Table2.OrigType ) AS OrigType,
    COALESCE( Table1.RebNo, Table2.RebNo) AS RebNo,
    COALESCE( Table1.RebNo, Table2.RebNo) AS RebAcc
FROM
    Table1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON
        Table1.Prog = Table2.Prog
        AND
        Table1.OrderNo = Table2.OrderNo
```

Comment: why the left join?

Comment: Why not a full outer join then? There's nothing in the question that states table1 should be preferred over table2.

Comment: @ConradFrix Agreed. A full outer join with a coalesce on every field (including the common field between the tables) would be a better solution here (assuming that the tables don't contain the full set of progs/orderids

Comment: thanks.looks like this worked but for some fields it is throwing error for varchar fields. conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'facility' to data type Int. any solution, or we have to write cast statement for each field ?

Comment: Also I think OrderNO should be in the join criteria. That's the OP's fault for not specifying and not aligning the fields well

Comment: @surya What are the full column type definitions of the two tables? You would only get that error if `facility` was an `int` in one table but `varchar` in another - if so, you have other problems to contend with.